# Changing textsize in iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am trying to change the font property using iText, but can't get it work. Do you have any opinion about what is wrong with this code?

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream createPersonnelReport(String sablonDir, String g,byte[] fotograf) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = null;
        try {
            baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            BaseFont fontTimes = BaseFont.createFont(sablonDir + File.separator + fontName, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sablonDir + File.separator + tmSablonForSicilKaydiName);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
            AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
            PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.getOverContent(1);

            form.setField("g", g);
            boolean check=form.setFieldProperty("g", "textsize", new Float(26), null);                                     
            System.out.println("check: "+ check);

            InputStream fotografImage = new ByteArrayInputStream(fotograf);
            BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(fotografImage);
            int type = bImageFromConvert.getType() == 0 ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB : bImageFromConvert.getType();
            BufferedImage dimensionedImage = resizeImage(bImageFromConvert, type);
            ImageIO.write(dimensionedImage, "jpg", new File("c:/yeniPersonelFoto.jpg"));
            Image image1 = Image.getInstance("c:/yeniPersonelFoto.jpg");
            image1.setAbsolutePosition(450f, 650f);
            canvas.addImage(image1);        
            stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
            stamper.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            return baos;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: check: true returns in the output

Comment: You create a BaseFont object all right... but you don't use it for anything! What do you expect to happen?

Comment: In the question I am not spesificly asking about the BaseFont object. It is there because I was trying another technique. I am asking about these lines of codes: "form.setField("g", g);        boolean check=form.setFieldProperty("g", "textsize", new Float(26), null); System.out.println("check: "+ check);

Comment: You are right. I saw that myself and tried to remove the comment, but on this mobile phone interface i can't find the delete button... Nonetheless sample code should be reduced to the issue at hand to prevent such misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

the answer was a missing line of code:

```
form.regenerateField("g");
```

solved the problem. After doing changes, you have to regenerate the field.